# Convert PDF to CSV using java

Tags: java, csv, pdf, tabula

I have tried most of the things on stack overflow and outside

**Problem** :
I have a pdf with contents and tables .
I need to parse tables and content as well.

**Apis :**
https://github.com/tabulapdf/tabula-java
I am using `tabula-java` which ignores some contents and contents inside table cells are not seporated proper way.

MY PDF IS having content like this

```
 DATE :1/1/2018         ABCD                   SCODE:FFFT
                       --ACCEPTED--
    USER:ADMIN         BATCH:RR               EEE
    CON BATCH
    =======================================================================
    MAIN SNO SUB  VALUE DIS %
    R    12   rr1 0125  24.5
            SLNO  DESC  QTY  TOTAL  CODE   FREE
            1     ABD   12   90     BBNEW  -NILL-
            2     XDF   45   55     GHT55  MRP
            3     QWE   08   77     CAT    -NILL-
    =======================================================================
    MAIN SNO SUB  VALUE DIS %
    QW    14   rr2 0122  24.5
            SLNO  DESC  QTY  TOTAL  CODE   FREE
            1     ABD   12   90     BBNEW  -NILL-
            2     XDF   45   55     GHT55  MRP
            3     QWE   08   77     CAT    -NILL-
```

Tabula code to convert :

```
public static void toCsv() throws ParseException {
        String commandLineOptions[] = { "-p", "1", "-o", "$csv", };
        CommandLineParser parser = new DefaultParser();
        try {
            CommandLine line = parser.parse(TabulaUtil.buildOptions(), commandLineOptions);
            new TabulaUtil(System.out, line).extractFileInto(
                    new File("/home/sample/firstPage.pdf"),
                    new File("/home/sample/onePage.csv"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

tabula even supports command line interface

```
java -jar TabulaJar/tabula-1.0.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar -p all  -o  $csv -b Pdfs
```

I have tried using `-c,--columns <COLUMNS>` of tabula 
which is takes cells by X coordinates of column boundaries

But the problem is my pdfs content is dynamic. i.e table sizes are changed.

These links in stack overflow and many more dint worked for me.

[How to convert PDF to CSV with tabula-py?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49560486/how-to-convert-pdf-to-csv-with-tabula-py)

[How to extract table data from PDF as CSV from the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30310416/how-to-extract-table-data-from-pdf-as-csv-from-the-command-line)

[Convert PDF to Excel in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49314190/convert-pdf-to-excel-in-java)

[How to convert a pdf file into CSV file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7581995/how-to-convert-a-pdf-file-into-csv-file)

[itext Converting PDF to csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11792465/itext-converting-pdf-to-csv)

[Parse PDF table and display it as CSV(Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38864370/parse-pdf-table-and-display-it-as-csvjava)

I have used pdf box which gives text which is unformatted where i cant read the table content properly.

Is posible to convert pdf with tables to **csv/excel** using java without loosing content and formatting.

**I dont want to use paid libraries .**

Comment: I don't think it's possible for any table in a PDF document. Those approaches are clearly limited to some extent, given that tables can have nested columns rows, e.g. using the multicolumn package of latex etc. - do you have an example PDF that doesn't work so far?

Comment: I think the entire way to a final CSV is illusory reading your findings. Displaying the PDF, your attempt and a repair/confirmation step seems the best feasible solution.

Comment: I agree with both @AKSW and @ Joop Eggen but one thing stuck in my mind is how this api can achive to convert perfectly with nested tables and contents. https://pdftables.com and it is a paid one.
This means there is a way. I want to know how ?

Comment: you know, there is a reason for being commercial, usually much more effort has been spent on it. The reason why can only somebody tell you, who knows the code of the commercial API and compared it to the Open Source projects. I mean, it's open source - you can also dig into the code and extend it. Or ask the devs. But don't forget, people might have done this just for their very restricted requirements where it worked. And you might not get any support

Comment: if you are looking for a commercial tool I'd suggest to have a look at pdf2Data from iText as well. It also extracts content from tables etc.

Answer (score 0):

See any example extracting PDF to CSV with Java here: https://github.com/pdftables/java-pdftables-api. Each page is considered indpendently so the dynamic nature of your PDFs should not be an issue. You can use the free trial on their site.

```
package com.pdftables.examples;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.config.CookieSpecs;
import org.apache.http.client.config.RequestConfig;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.CloseableHttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntityBuilder;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.FileBody;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;

public class ConvertToFile {
    private static List<String> formats = Arrays.asList(new String[] { "csv", "xml", "xlsx-single", "xlsx-multiple" });

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        if (args.length != 3) {
            System.out.println("Command line: <API_KEY> <FORMAT> <PDF filename>");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        final String apiKey = args[0];
        final String format = args[1].toLowerCase();
        final String pdfFilename = args[2];

        if (!formats.contains(format)) {
            System.out.println("Invalid output format: \"" + format + "\"");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        // Avoid cookie warning with default cookie configuration
        RequestConfig globalConfig = RequestConfig.custom().setCookieSpec(CookieSpecs.STANDARD).build();

        File inputFile = new File(pdfFilename);

        if (!inputFile.canRead()) {
            System.out.println("Can't read input PDF file: \"" + pdfFilename + "\"");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        try (CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom().setDefaultRequestConfig(globalConfig).build()) {
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://pdftables.com/api?format=" + format + "&key=" + apiKey);
            FileBody fileBody = new FileBody(inputFile);

            HttpEntity requestBody = MultipartEntityBuilder.create().addPart("f", fileBody).build();
            httppost.setEntity(requestBody);

            System.out.println("Sending request");

            try (CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost)) {
                if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 200) {
                    System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
                    System.exit(1);
                }
                HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
                if (resEntity != null) {
                    final String outputFilename = getOutputFilename(pdfFilename, format.replaceFirst("-.*$", ""));
                    System.out.println("Writing output to " + outputFilename);

                    final File outputFile = new File(outputFilename);
                    FileUtils.copyToFile(resEntity.getContent(), outputFile);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Error: file missing from response");
                    System.exit(1);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static String getOutputFilename(String pdfFilename, String suffix) {
        if (pdfFilename.length() >= 5 && pdfFilename.toLowerCase().endsWith(".pdf")) {
            return pdfFilename.substring(0, pdfFilename.length() - 4) + "." + suffix;
        } else {
            return pdfFilename + "." + suffix;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apache foundation has few projects

Tikka supports wide range of extensions including pdf, ppt, xls. Supported formats are mentioned in https://tika.apache.org/1.24.1/formats.html

https://tika.apache.org/

PDF Box - Specific to pdf related features

https://pdfbox.apache.org/